# Filling in HTML select tag from C++ addon function call

Tags: javascript, node.js, node.js-addon, node-addon-api

I'm just not sure how to approach this. I have a blank select tag in my HTML with JS handling click events. I then have a addon built that builds some objects from other sources each containing an unique identifying string.

How would I go about filling in the select tag from the data in the addon?

I can't find a way to fill it in the C++ addon, but I also can't think of a clean way to have the Javascript call a single function to fill it in completely.

Comment: there is not enough information here to understand the problem. it's not at all clear that there is any need for a C++ addon to fill in portions of HTML, try providing some background and maybe some code too.

Comment: Can't provide any code because I'm not even sure of how to approach this. I need the addon to fill it in because the addon accesses system resources (addon is for an Electron app) to fill in the selection at runtime.

Comment: Is there an HTML template that must be filled in? What must be filled in? Why is it not possible for the addon to return the system resources-derived information and let JavaScript fill in the tags? You don't provide an example of anything that allows anyone to formulate an answer.